# error: 'rust-analyzer' is not installed for the toolchain 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

I have installed rust-analyzer following the instructions at https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#installation :

```
✔ ~> rustup component add rust-src
info: component 'rust-src' is up to date
```

However, I get:

```
✔ ~> rust-analyzer -v
error: 'rust-analyzer' is not installed for the toolchain 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
```

I have tried to install for this specific toolchain too:

```
✘-1 ~> rustup component add rust-src --toolchain stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
info: component 'rust-src' is up to date
```

But I still get the same error.

I have looked for the error on the internet, and found for example discussions at  https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/14776 . However, checking the executable location returns

```
✔ ~> which rust-analyzer
/home/jrmet/.cargo/bin/rust-analyzer
```

which is well within my PATH. Also, I can do:

```
✔ ~> /home/jrmet/.cargo/bin/rust-analyzer
error: 'rust-analyzer' is not installed for the toolchain 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
```

I have been working also with other targets:

```
✔ ~> rustup target list | grep installed
thumbv7em-none-eabihf (installed)
thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf (installed)
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (installed)
```

but I do not think this should play a role?

Any idea why I have this issue and how to fix it? I have a feeling I may have messed up somehow with targets and toolchains, but no idea how / where / how to fix it.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: You didn't install `rust-analyzer`, you only installed `rust-src` (which is a dependency of it).

Comment: Aaah, thanks - I had misunderstood the instructions.

Comment: Sorry for such a "stupid" mistake, thanks for the help. What confused me is that which and my system actually pointed to something called ```rust-analyzer```, so I would not have thought that it was actually not installed... Weird / I am certainly missing something, but now it works ^^ .

Comment: "Stupid mistakes" are welcome here as long as they follow the posted guidelines. You had a question in good faith with all the necessary documentation linked. That's better than half the questions here. Don't ever put yourself down for learning!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had misunderstood the instructions on how to install rust-analyzer: what I had installed were just the dependencies, not rust-analyzer itself.

To fix this, following the instruction page:

```
✔ ~> rustup component add rust-analyzer
info: downloading component 'rust-analyzer'
info: installing component 'rust-analyzer'
✔ ~> rust-analyzer --version
rust-analyzer 1.73.0 (cc66ad4 2023-10-03)
```

My confusion stemmed from the fact that there was an executable rust-analyzer that was detected by `which` and was launched automatically, even though rust-analyzer was not actually installed...

Comment: The executable detected is probably the wrapper that rustup provides, which launches the real executable with the correct environment variables and flags.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That really confused me ^^ . Hope other users with the same issue will hit this answer in the future - I could not find this reported so far, I was maybe missing something :) .

Comment: @Zorglub29, for further reading: The reason rustup uses a wrapper executable is because it is platform agnostic. You could have rust-analyzer available for multiple targets on the same machine, and the wrapper is responsible for delegating to the correct executable for the correct target.

Comment: (maybe having a slightly different name for the wrapper and the delegate would help? :) )